# Inserting Element single linked List C

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I try to insert an Element in an empty single Linked List and print that.
The code looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Node{
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
}ll;

void addElement(ll* List, int num){
ll* new = malloc(sizeof(ll));

if(new == NULL){
printf("NO MEMORY\n");
exit(0);
}

new->val = num;
new->next = NULL;

if(List == NULL){
List = new;
return;
}

ll* curr = List;
while(curr->next != NULL){
curr = curr->next;
}
curr->next = new;
}


void printElements(ll* List){

ll* curr = List;

while(curr != NULL){
printf("%i\n", curr->val);
curr = curr->next;
}
}
*int main(){
ll* list = NULL;
addElement(list, 20);
addElement(list, 30);
addElement(list, 19);
printElements(list);

return 0;*
}
```

### Does anybody see my mistake? Because it only works if i already have an Element in my List and nothing will be printed.

Comment: With a variable named `new`, this isn't possibly C++.  Also, given your recent "answer", you may still [edit] this question to remove typos or otherwise clarify your question.

Comment: its pure c sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer to the head node used as the function argument.

```
void addElement(ll* List, int num){
```

So this statement

```
List = new;
```

does not change the value of the original pointer. It changes the value of the copy of the original pointer.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int addElement( ll **List, int num )
{
    ll *new_node = malloc( sizeof( ll ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->val = num;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *List != NULL ) List = &( *List )->next;

        *List = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
ll* list = NULL;
addElement( &list, 20);
addElement( &list, 30);
addElement( &list, 19);
```